# Wordpress images not visible because of “This webpage has a redirect loop” error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, redirect, nginx

I have word press in my magento's root folder under `blog` directory. This blog directory was copied from a live site to my application. (I am using fish pig magento extension for the word press integration in Magento)

```
/var/www/
      app
      blog
```

In magento admin I have set *Use Web Server Rewrites* to **NO**

I have following path for the images in front end

```
http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/blogimage-150x150.png
```

This image exists at the specified location. File permissions are `777` for the directories and files.But the image is not visible in front end blog pages.

When I manually enter this image url in my Chrome browser I am getting *`This webpage has a redirect loop`* error. in it.

`.htaccess` file which is under blog folder is having only this line `DirectoryIndex index.php`

I have also tried these commands

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

The application is hosted on nginx

**Update**

If I place an image at **http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/sample.jpg** location , I am unable to access this also.

How can I fix this redirect loop, is there any one who can help?

Comment: what does the htaccess in your root folder contain?

Comment: `nginx` will not parse your htaccess http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess

Comment: @masegaloeh What do you mean to say I am not getting.

Comment: @KristofFeys Feys In the magento roor I have .htaccess file for the magento and in blog folder I have ..htcess containing this            DirectoryIndex index.php

Comment: Even there is a `.htaccess` in your folder, `nginx` will not include any configuration in that file. In other words, your `.htaccess` will be useless in `nginx` environment

Comment: @masegaloeh Could you please suggest some solution to my issue.I am trying this since last 6 hours but not solution worked for me.

Comment: Unless you can provide us your `nginx` configuration, we are only blind guessing in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is fixed now. I read the documentation of the fishpig. It is mentioned there under the installation guide.  *If you want your blog to be viewable on http://www.yourmagento.com/blog, do not install WordPress in a sub-directory named blog. For this reason it is recommended that you install WordPress in a sub-directory named wp*

In my case the name of the wordpress directory and the blog url both were same ie. blog. When I changed the directory name of wordpress from blog to blogs and changed the same setting under the admin for fishpig integration. Every thing started working fine.

[image: error notice in magento admin]

Fix

[image: Correct settings]

If your wordpress have url as www.example.com/blog , then directory structure should be like following

```
/var/www/
      app
      blogs (or something other than blog)
```