# Wordpress implementation in Magento nesting loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento, nested

I am busy with the migration of our current site to Magento and i am stuck with the fishpig wordpress plugin. I have copied the wordpress folder into the root of magento with the name wp. I also installed the fishpig plugin in magento. Now whenever i try to access the page i get a nesting error "Front controller reached 100 router match iterations". I don't know why it's stuck in an infinite nesting loop but i figure it has something to do with the configuration and .htaccess. Except i can't figure out what.

This is my .htaccess from the wp folder:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

My wordpress database has the following values:

```
siteurl: http://ip/path/index.php/wp
home   : http://ip/path/index.php/blog
```

My Magento Fishpig configuration has the following values

```
Home url: blog
Pad     : wp
```

Does anyone know the correct configuration to make this work? If any other information is needed please feel free to ask.

Comment: Please look in to this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752336/wordpress-images-not-visible-because-of-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-error/24141375#24141375

Comment: The configuration is already like in the link you gave. Thank you anyway